# Galera cluster consume many CPU percent and CPU high load

Tags: performance, mariadb, load, galera

I have implemented a cluster include three nodes: two stored nodes and one garbd (also haproxy - load balancer).

Some information about servers:
SSD 480G Raid1
Memory 32G
Swap 16G
2xCPU, number of cores: 24
Maria Galera Cluster 10.0.14

mysqld process consume CPU percent so much 229.3% - 300%

The highes CPU load 20-30.

When CPU load grow up, there is some log like that.

```
*** Victim TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 17362851, ACTIVE 5 sec
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
809 lock struct(s), heap size 95784, 149905 row lock(s), undo log entries 19493
MySQL thread id 182155, OS thread handle 0x7fc587451700, query id 1566816, query end
    *** WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 180 page no 764 n bits 288 index `PRIMARY` of table `xxx`.`yyy` trx id 17362851 lock_mode X
141128 10:36:45 [Note] WSREP: cluster conflict due to high priority abort for threads:
141128 10:36:45 [Note] WSREP: Winning thread: 
   THD: 22, mode: applier, state: executing, conflict: no conflict, seqno: 1447458
   SQL: (null)
141128 10:36:45 [Note] WSREP: Victim thread: 
   THD: 182155, mode: local, state: committing, conflict: no conflict, seqno: -1
```

I don't know why galera get cert fail because I am using master-slave. There is only node receiving writeset from clients.

Some solution I am applying:

```
set wsrep_auto_increment_control=OFF on two nodes
set query_cache_size=1G
Decrease wsrep_slave_thread from 48 to 24
```

Now, my CPU load is in range 2.00-3.00 I am waiting and observing.
What can I do for better performance. I am mangaing use thread pool for decrease CPU percent usage of mysqld.